# Remove NetSuite Sublist Button

Tags: netsuite, sublist, suitescript

I have a NetSuite Suitelet script that is listing all of a customer's credit cards so that they can edit the cards themselves.

I would like to remove the "remove" button from that sublist, if possible.  I've looked all over the NetSuite support site, with no luck.  Has anyone encountered this before?

Below is the code that I have:

```
var creditCardSublist=form.addSubList('custpage_credit_card_sublist','inlineeditor','Current Credit Cards');

/* this does not work */
form.removeButton('custpage_credit_card_sublist_remove');

/* this does not work either*/
creditCardSublist.removeButton('custpage_credit_card_sublist_remove');
```

Thanks for any assistance with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually client side is what you have to do.

You create a client script to go along with your suitelet.
use form.setScript... to associate it.

in the client script create an initLine function. That function can use jQuery (automatically included by Netsuite) to find and remove the Remove button.

This is a hack but Netsuite doesn't have any API for manipulating those lists

Comment: Thanks.  I did not think about using jQuery on the client side to remove it.  jQuery could definitely handle any script issues I run into.  Great idea!

The solution I went with (after being told by NetSuite that it is not possible to remove that button), was just to add in a comparison function into the script to double check all of the original rows against the new rows.

Answer (score -1):

> addSubList(name, type, label, tab) takes a type parameter, which decides the sub list type.

1. editor - An edit sublist with non-inline form fields
2. inlineeditor - An edit sublist with inline fields
3. list - A list sublist with editable fields
4. staticlist - A read-only segmentable list sublist.

So you might want to use a `staticlist` type.

Comment: This would not work, since the form is for customers to edit their own CC information.  Being a read-only list would not allow that feature.

Answer (score -1):

use this jQuery in relevant client script.

```
    jQuery(".uir-insert").remove();
    jQuery(".uir-remove").remove();
    jQuery('#custpage_so_sublist_insert').hide();
    jQuery('#custpage_so_sublist_remove').hide();
```

Note:
you can only use jquery in clienscript so you must create client script along with suitelet script.

Comment: Why do they have to use jQuery?